# Why do email tracking beacons/pixels often contain long, obscured pieces of code? Wouldn't any image achieve the same purpose?

Tags: email, pixel, tracking

I've noticed tracking pixels often looks like this:  https://example.com/track/op=
en.php?u=3D110b1a6bc44bea94eacce1665&id=3Dc3927abd47&e=3D899283f051" heig=ht=3D"1" width=3D"1">

What is going on there with the u=3D110b1a6bc44bea94eacce1665&id=3Dc3927abd47&e=3D899283f051"

This appears to be a dynamically generated snippet, specific to a given recipient of an email.

Wouldn't embedding a simple pixel.gif achieve the same purpose, with the IP address (and other header information) being transmitted to the server and available in its logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you send bulk mail you wanna identify which exact user opened your mail. Thats why you need to identify each letter. Such a code in url allows to identify both email campaing and receiver. Passing them directly in get param like utm-term isn't secure and allows to manipulate it easily.